# Assembly only digit input

Tags: assembly, input, tasm

I found some code online that lets the user type a number, without worrying about how many digits it has:

```
proc getInput
    mov [userAnswer], 0
    READ:
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21H
    
    CMP AL, 13
    JE ENDOFNUMBER
    
    MOV VALUE, AL
    SUB VALUE, 48
    
    MOV AL, [userAnswer]
    MOV BL, 10
    MUL BL
    
    ADD AL, VALUE
    
    MOV [userAnswer], AL
    
    JMP READ

    ENDOFNUMBER:   

    ret
endp getInput
```

How can I make sure the user only types digits?
I am trying to make it so it doesn't print characters like: "t", "a", "$" when the user types them.

For example:
when the user types "5", it will write 5, but it won't be the same for "t".

Comment: Check the character for being `<= '9'` and `>= '0'`  (Or that `c - '0' <= 9` unsigned).  Otherwise prompt again.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when the user *does* enter `'t'` or something?